# Finding min and max value of the table in a constant time

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains relative large data,
so that it takes too long for the statements below:

```
SELECT MIN(column) FROM table WHERE ...
SELECT MAX(column) FROM table WHERE ...
```

I tried index the column, but the performance still does not suffice my need.

I also thought of caching min and max value in another table by using trigger or event.
But my MySQL version is 5.0.51a which requires SUPER privilege for trigger and does not support event.

It is IMPOSSIBLE for me to have SUPER privilege or to upgrade MySQL.
(If possible, then no need to ask!)

How to solve this problem just inside MySQL?
That is, without the help of OS.

Comment: Can you give a definition of the table?

Comment: "a table which contains relative large data" - how large? "the performance still does not suffice my need" - how slow is your query?

Comment: If you're executing both queries individually to get both min and max, combine them into a single query. The WHERE clause that you're using may also make a lot of difference... a simple index on column is unlikely to make much difference

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the query you are running? As Mark Baker said, what's in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

If your `column` is indexed, you should find `min(column)` near instantly, because that is the first value MySQL will find.
Same goes for `max(column)` on an indexed column.

If you cannot add an index for some reason the following triggers will cache the MIN and MAX value in a separate table.

Note that TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_table1_each AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE db_info i 
    SET i.minimum = LEAST(i.minimum, NEW.col) 
       ,i.maximum = GREATEST(i.maximum, NEW.col)
       ,i.min_count = (i.min_count * (new.col < i.minumum)) 
                      + (i.minimum = new.col) + (i.minimum < new.col)
       ,i.max_count = (i.max_count * (new.col > i.maximum))
                      + (i.maximum = new.col) + (new.col > i.maximum)
    WHERE i.tablename = 'table1'; 
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_table1_each AFTER DELETE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE new_min_count INTEGER;
  DECLARE new_max_count INTEGER;

  UPDATE db_info i 
    SET i.min_count = i.min_count - (i.minimum = old.col)
       ,i.max_count = i.max_count - (i.maximum = old.col)
    WHERE i.tablename = 'table1';
  SELECT i.min_count INTO new_min_count, i.max_count INTO new_max_count
    FROM db_info i
    WHERE i.tablename = 'table1';

  IF new_max_count = 0 THEN 
    UPDATE db_info i
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(col) as new_max FROM table1) m
      SET i.max_count = 1  
         ,i.maximum = m.new_max;
  END IF;
  IF new_min_count = 0 THEN
    UPDATE db_info i
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(col) as new_min FROM table1) m
      SET i.min_count = 1  
         ,i.minimum = m.new_min;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The `after update` trigger will be some mix of the insert and delete triggers.